# Upload blob into Azure Blob Storage with specified ContentType and overwrite same time (.NET v12 SDK)?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to upload `Blob` from `Stream` with .Net 12 SDK, setting `ContentType` and `overwrite` property to true same time.

There are few overloads of `BlobClient.Upload` method. But none of them accepts both parameters.

As an alternative I can set `ContentType` in the second step, but would prefer to do in one.

```
BlobHttpHeaders blobHttpHeaders = new BlobHttpHeaders();
blobHttpHeaders.ContentType = "text/xml";
blobClient.SetHttpHeaders(blobHttpHeaders);
```

Is that possible in one run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The efficient way to do the same with a single method is as follows,

```cs
await blobClient.UploadAsync(ms, new BlobHttpHeaders{ ContentType = "text/xml"});
```

OR

```cs
 using Stream stream = file.ToStream();
 var result = await blobClient.UploadAsync(stream, new BlobHttpHeaders { ContentType = "text/xml" });
```

Comment: Thanks! Did not find in docs, that this overload sets `overwrite ` to `true`.